# Python regex to search substring in multiline string variable

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to search for group of words in a multiline string variable. I can do this by

```
>>> test_1 = """--Comment
... /*Comment*/
... MERGE fhkjfsk lkfjs;lfks;f
... hdkjdkd
... fjlkf
... """
>>> m = re.search(r"(insert|merge|update|delete)\s*", test_1, re.IGNORECASE)
>>> print(m)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(22, 28), match='MERGE '>
```

But I want to match only those words that are present in a line that doesn't start with "--" or "/*". So I don't want following to match:

```
>>> test_1 = """--Comment
... /*Comment*/
... --MERGE fhkjfsk lkfjs;lfks;f
... hdkjdkd
... fjlkf
... """
>>> m = re.search(r"(insert|merge|update|delete)\s*", test_1, re.IGNORECASE)
>>> print(m)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(24, 30), match='MERGE '>
```

This is what I am unable to get to work. I have tried:

```
>>> test_1 = """--Comment
... /*Comment*/
... --MERGE fhkjfsk lkfjs;lfks;f
... INSERT fhskjfsf
... gfdsjhs
... """
>>> m = re.search(r"^(?!--)(insert|merge|update|delete)\s*", test_1, re.IGNORECASE)
>>> print(m)
None
>>>
```

I think I need something in between the two parenthesis `(?!--)(insert|merge|update|delete)` and have tried adding

.+ like `(?!--).+(insert|merge|update|delete)`

\s* like `(?!--)\s*(insert|merge|update|delete)`

. like `(?!--).(insert|merge|update|delete)`

.* like `(?!--).*(insert|merge|update|delete)`but it doesn't help.

Any suggestions on how to get this working would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex is fine, but the `^` matches only the start of the whole string. You should use `re.MULTILINE` to make it match starts of lines.

```
re.search(r"^(?!--)(insert|merge|update|delete)\s*", test_1, re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
```

Comment: Thank you. This answers my question. I am a bit confused with following though. Shouldn't first search find and match "MERGE"?
`SyntaxError: EOF while scanning triple-quoted string literal
>>> test_1 = """--INSERT
... /*MERGE*/
... hi there
... you are
... """
>>> m = re.search(r"^(?!--)(insert|merge|update|tere)\s*", test_1, re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
>>> print(m)
None
>>> m = re.search(r"^(?!--)(?!/*)(insert|merge|update|delete)\s*", test_1, re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
>>> print(m)
None
>>>`